# NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

I'm trying to filter a file searching program by lastModified date, using the Epoch value as a comparisson.

When I try to execute this, it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1408350905359"

Apparently the initial value of my variable is empty, and I've been told to make sure to do a validation or an exception to make it not... well, be empty. Thing is, I suck and can't. I'll post the code in which I'm having problems. Can someone help?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                        
   String direcdate=direc1.getText();
   String Phrase = (" Pastas/Ficheiros em: '" + direcdate + "  ----- : ' ");

   File folder = new File(direcdate);
   File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();

   for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
   {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
     long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();        

      String str = ultimaalt.getText();

      int q =Integer.valueOf(str);
      long DIAS = q*86400000;
      long currentdate;
      currentdate = epoch - (q*DIAS);
      String lastmodstr;
      lastmodstr = valueOf(listOfFile.lastModified());

      //NAO CONSIGO METER ESTA MERDA A FUNCIONAR
      // PRECISO DUM TRY CATCH EXCEPTION
      // AGORA QUAL?
      // fml.exe

      int lastmodint;           
      lastmodint=Integer.valueOf(lastmodstr);

       if (lastmodint<= currentdate)
       {
         if(listOfFile.isFile())
         {   
           Phrase = (Phrase + " \n -->"
                     + listOfFile.getName ()
                     + "      Ultima alteração:"
                     + sdf.format(listOfFile.lastModified())
                     + ". ");   
        } else if (listOfFile.isDirectory()) {
          Phrase = (Phrase + " \n -->"
                    + listOfFile.getName() 
                    + "(Pasta)" + "     Ultima alteração:" 
                    + sdf.format(listOfFile.lastModified()) 
                    + ". ");
        } else {}
       }
     }

     jTextPane1.setText(Phrase); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

EDIT:

Fixed!

The answer was changing:

> int lastmodint;
>             lastmodint=Integer.valueOf(lastmodstr);

to

> Long lastmodint;

```
        lastmodint=Long.valueOf(lastmodstr);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your string does not represent any `int` value. Try `long` instead, or `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! For somereason I forgot the epoch value usually surpassed the Int threshold!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to not make it empty, throw an exception, like so:

```
String str = ultimaalt.getText();
if (str == null) {
   throw new NullPointerException("No text captured.");
}

if (str.isEmpty()) {
   throw new InvalidStateException("No text captured.");
}
```

Also, your value is a `long`, not an `int`, so `Long.valueOf()` will be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple Change is needed in your code to be done

**replace**:

```
int lastmodint;

        lastmodint=Integer.valueOf(lastmodstr);
```

**to**

```
int lastmodint;

            lastmodint=Integer.parseInt(lastmodstr);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: That doesn't solve the OP's question at all. The `valueOf()` method calls the `parseInt()` method internally.

Comment: OP here.
I changed:
>int lastmod int;
lastmodint=Integer.valueOf(lastmodstr);

to

>long lastmodint;
lastmodint=Long.valueOf(lastmodstr);